# How to switch .net runtime?

Tags: .net, version

I have modified the .exe.config and added the following lines

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
<requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
```

However, Fusion shows that run time 2.0 is used. How to change the run-time version ?

upd:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="VPI.AppEngine" type="VPI.Application.Base.ConfigurationSectionHandler, VPI.Application, Version=5.11.70.30, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fcf3ef807983b7b6"/>
</configSections>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
</startup>
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <qualifyAssembly partialName="VPI.DesignRule" fullName="VPI.DesignRule,version=6.4.0.0,publicKeyToken=fcf3ef807983b7b6,culture=neutral"/>
        <qualifyAssembly partialName="VPI.NetworkPlanning" fullName="VPI.NetworkPlanning,version=6.4.0.0,publicKeyToken=fcf3ef807983b7b6,culture=neutral"/>
        <qualifyAssembly partialName="VPI.DataModel.ConfigurationData" fullName="VPI.DataModel.ConfigurationData,version=6.4.0.0,publicKeyToken=fcf3ef807983b7b6,culture=neutral"/>
        <probing privatePath="Libraries;Libraries\ThirdParty"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
    <clear/>
    <remove name="Default"/>
    <add name="TextLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\1.txt" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
    <switches>
        <add name="SystemMessageSwitch" value="4"/>
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Please show your complete configuration file.

Comment: I've added the file but omited the section with the private data because it's size is more than 200 kb

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the version string you're using. From the [`supportedRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) documentation:

> A string value that specifies the version of the common language runtime (CLR) that this application supports. The first three versions of the CLR are specified by "v1.0.3705", "v1.1.4322", and "v2.0.50727". Beginning with the .NET Framework version 4, only the major and minor version numbers are required (that is, "v4.0" instead of "v4.0.30319"). The shorter string is recommended.

So you should try:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<requiredRuntime version="v4.0"/>
```

Comment: I've tried my lines on different application and they works fine. Are there any other way to change the version ? Or, what can be the reason of such behavior ?

Comment: @MadHollander: It's hard to say, to be honest. Can you come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? Have you *tried* the short version?

Comment: I've tried the short version but nothing chaged. The main problem that I can't create small application to demonstrate.

Comment: @MadHollander: How certain are you that it's taking *any* notice of your config file? If you deliberately make that file invalid, what happens? (I'm just wondering whether it's actually loading a similar but different file...)

Comment: Ideed, looks like app ignores the values even when they are wrong. Test application shows message box about wrong runtime, but my application runs without any error.

Comment: @MadHollander: Right - so it's not loading your config file at all, I suspect. What kind of app is it, where is your config file, and how are you running it?

Comment: Actually, this file contains all required information - components, UI and etc. When I delete this file, app just don't start. So, I suppose, only startup section looks like ignored.

Comment: @MadHollander: Okay, that's odd. So again, what kind of app is this?

Comment: This is winforms application, but starts from native exe file and uses some app domains

Comment: @MadHollander: Ah - well that's almost certainly the reason then. (I wish you'd mentioned it before.) How exactly does the native exe load it? If it's hosting the CLR itself, then that *won't* go through the startup parts when it loads your app.

Comment: Thank you ! Looks like I found the reason

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the reason - bootstrapper uses CorBindToRuntimeEx and msdn tells that this case startup element is ignored

Jon Skeet - thank you very much ;-)